# calling multiple function in hook menu in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

i try to call more than one function in a single hook_menu functionality..but am not getting more than one functionality in the page callback..please help me to solve this..below is my code i try to access getvalue_my_form and getvalue_show in a pagecallback..

```
     <?php
  global $ema;
  $ema=$_POST['email'];

   drupal_set_message('email:'.$ema);

   function getvalue_menu() {
   $items = array();
    $items['formtest1'] = array(
    'title' => 'valuegetting',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('getvalue_my_form'),
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     );

    return $items;
   }
   function getvalue_my_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['image_file'] = array(
   '#title' => t('upload Banner:'),
   '#type' => 'file',
    );
   return $form; 
   }
  function getvalue_show()
    {
   $em="hi welcome";
    return $em;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drupal hooking system won't be mixed with general php page coding. Ex.

you don't write global $ema; etc outside of hook function. If you want to call two functions assuming your module name is getvalue, you probably want to do this.

```
function getvalue_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['formtest1'] = array(
        'title' => 'valuegetting',
        'page callback' => 'getvalue_two_functions',
        'page arguments' => array(),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     );

    return $items;
}

function getvalue_two_functions() {
    // call first function
    $two_values['first'] = 1;

    // call second function
    $two_values['second'] = 2;

    return $two_values;
}
```

When you type formtest1 in URL, it'll reach getvalue_two_functions(). Form function is just another drupal call, you can call

```
drupal_get_form('getvalue_my_form');
```

inside getvalue_two_functions().

Comment: when am calling two functions inside get_two functions..its retrieving first function only..its not retrieving the second function..

Comment: yes how to retrieve from both function if both function are returning some valued .... or if one function is form and another function is simple function which is returning some value then how to retrive second function value in form submit handler ????